# How do I check if the count of a list is increasing?

Tags: c#

I have this list:

```
List<string> x=new List<string>
```

So, now I want to do something when the count is being increased. I tried:

```
if(x.Count++){
  //do stuff
}
```

But it did not work. So what can I try?

Comment: Tunnel all adding of elements trough your own delegate method which activates an event.

Comment: All together the code isn't that extensive; it sounds more than it is. You have to utilize event handlers that aren't directly available so you have to work around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this like you're trying to do. `if (x.Count++)` makes no sense - you're attempting to *increment* the count (which is read-only).

I would derive from `List<T>` and add `ItemAdded` and `ItemRemoved` events.

Actually, that would be re-inventing the wheel. Such a collection already exists. See [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), which raises a [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event. The [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx) tells you what changed.

Example (not tested):

```
void ChangeHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
    switch (e.Action) {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            // One or more items were added to the collection.
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
            // One or more items were moved within the collection.
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            // One or more items were removed from the collection.
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            // One or more items were replaced in the collection.
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            // The content of the collection changed dramatically.
            break;
    }

    // The other properties of e tell you where in the list
    // the change took place, and what was affected.
}

void test() {
    var myList = ObservableCollection<int>();
    myList.CollectionChanged += ChangeHandler;

    myList.Add(4);
}
```

References:

- [`NotifyCollectionChangedAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction.aspx)

Comment: Looks like the solution. You'll have to check the initial size and the current size of the list to find out if something has been added or removed; the appropriate event doesn't seem to differentiate between the two.

Comment: The `List.Add()` method and other relevant methods are non-virtual so you can't really make that work. You would have to reimplement list to do that.

Comment: +1 Or `BindingList<T>` which has  events for every type of mutation. It has also the [`AddingNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132741.aspx) event which is raised _before_ an item is added.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the alternative solution (which of course is better for binding). However `"has events for every type of mutation"` doesn't seem accurate - it has essentially the same, single [`ListChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132740(v=vs.110).aspx).